# What concept should I learn in Probability to make a sense of this question?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It has been years since I last studied Probability, please feel free to correct any mistakes in my approach.

<strike>What is the **average** number of distinct numbers in N random non-negative numbers less than a thousand?</strike>

Given integers from 0 to 999 (inclusive). Choose N integers such that all integers are equally likely to be selected. How many distinct integers do you have in N on average?

[Edit:

I changed the following question (from a textbook about algorithms) into the one I asked above.

What is the average number of distinct keys that FrequencyCounter will find
among N random nonnegative integers less than 1,000, for N=10, 10^2 , 10^3 , 10^4, 10^5, and 10^6 ?

My understanding of the question is from 1...999 you select N numbers randomly, that is in no specific way. I think we can assume selecting each number is equally likely. Repetitions are allowed. Now do this for infinite times. Take a note of all results for each experiment somehow and assume all those results are equally likely. Now pick one of the results. How many distinct numbers are that in that result on average?

]

Here is my attempt:

I can choose 1000^N different lists of numbers, that is any number may repeat with any frequency in a list of size N.

If I were to choose sets (distinct numbers in the list) of size N, then the number of different sets should be P(1000, N) (permutations). However in the context of the question order of the elements should not be significant, so the correct number should be C(1000, N) (combinations).

The probability of me choosing all distinct numbers should be Px = C(1000, N)/(1000^N).

Now, how do I get to calculate an average number? Is it 1000 * Px? Somehow this doesn't sound right.

By the way, is my understanding of **average number** correct? I mean, I do this experiment infinite times and the number of distinct numbers in that set converges to a number which we call average? Though I am guessing that number should depend on the distribution of distinct numbers and calculated accordingly.

Comment: I'd use linearity.  For each $n$ on the list compute the probability that it is selected at least once.  Multiply by the number of $n$.

Comment: While I agree, lulu, this doesn't seem to actually answer any of the OP's questions.

Comment: @JohnHughes  In truth, I can't follow the OP's proposed method...so I proposed another.

Comment: It is not possible to solve as there is not enough information: What is meant by "random"?  What is meant by "number less than 1000"?  Are these integers or real numbers?  What is their distribution? Are they drawn independently?

Comment: For what it's worth:  I read the question as asking "suppose you choose $N$ numbers independently and uniformly at random from $(1,2,\cdots, 999)$. With replacement, just to be clear.  What is the expected number of distinct selections, as a function of $N$?"  Thus, if $N=5$ and you, improbably, select, $\{1,2,1,1,1\}$ then the answer, on this trial, would be $2$.  Yes, "expected number" or "average" are intended to represent the predicted average result of a large number of trials, but, of course, [Expected Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) has a clear, formal definition.

Comment: Michael I am sorry, I should have been more precise. Numbers are integers. Random means "randomly selected". Let me give you an example. From 1 to 1000, randomly select 20 numbers . Order doesn't matter, do this experiment infinite times. What is the average number of distinct numbers should be in a single experiment?

Comment: To be clear:  I am, of course, not certain that I have stated the problem the way you intended.  For instance, you might be choosing from $(0,1,\cdots , 999)$ or some other variant.  Either way, you should clarify.

Comment: Let me jump in here and say that you've got a reasonable question, and it's great that you've asked it, and these comments are all just attempts to make sure that we end up answering the question you really wanted to ask. They can sometimes seem a little aggressive, or picky, but folks who know a lot about the topic may be able to see their significance even if you cannot. Anyhow, keep up the good work: address these comments to the degree possible until someone provides what will be (I hope) a nice clear answer. And welcome to MSE!

Comment: Thank you for your support, John. I am familiar with Maths and I know details really matter. I went a bit sloppy in my style. My mistake. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a complete answer, but a rephrasing of the question and some remarks related to your questions.**

I *think* your question can be reduced to the following.

Consider the set $U$ of all sequences 
$$
u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n,
$$
where each $u_1$ is an integer between $1$ and $1000$. $U$ can be made into a probability space by assigning equal probability, $\frac{1}{1000^n}$ to each sequence in $U$.

For a typical sequence $u$, the number of distinct items in the sequence $u$ is some number between $1$ and $n$; let's call that $f(u)$. Then $f$ is a function from $U$ to the set $\{1, \ldots n\}$. It has an "average value", which is 
$$
Av(f) = \sum_{u \in U} f(u) p(u)
$$
where $p(u) = \frac{1}{1000^n}$ is the probability associated to $u$. Because this is a constant, it can be pulled out of the sum to get
$$
Av(f) = \frac{1}{1000^n} \sum_{u \in U} f(u),
$$
which reflects your idea of "count up distinct items in each list and average them".

The thing you computed in your description is rather different. There's a *different* function $g : U \to \{0, 1\}$ which assigns $1$ to $u$ if all items in the sequence are distinct, and $0$ otherwise. And you've figured out that the average value for $g$ is $C(1000, n) / 1000^n$. Unfortunately, that average value doesn't tell you much of anything about the average value of $f$.

Actually, it *does* tell you *something*. For the sum
$$
\sum_{u \in U} f(u)
$$
over all sequences can be *estimated* very crudely. Let's let $S \subset U$ consist of exactly those sequences whose entries are all different. Then 
$$
\sum_{u \in U} f(u) \ge  \sum_{u \in S} f(u)
$$
And for each $u \in S$, we *know* what $f(u)$ is: it's just $n$. So we can say
\begin{align} 
\sum_{u \in U} f(u) &\ge  \sum_{u \in S} f(u) \\
&=  \sum_{u \in S} n \\
&=  n \sum_{u \in S} 1
\end{align}
which is just $n$ times the number of elements in $S$, which you've already determined is $C(1000, n)$. So we know that 
$$
Av(f) \ge \frac{1}{1000^n} \left(n \cdot C(1000,n) \right).
$$
But that is, of course, just a crude estimate. So while your approach was partly correct, and told you *something* it doesn't really get you where you need to go.

To actually get the answer you need, you somehow need to sum up $f(u)$ for all $u \in U$. And to do that, @lulu's idea of linearity of expectation is probably the right road to go down, but I leave that to someone else to write out. I just wanted to (1) try to phrase the question unambiguously, and (2) try to address the question of how to get from the work you'd done to the answer you needed (short answer: you really can't, but you can get a weak estimate).

Comment: Wow. Thank you for putting that into a formal mathematical perspective. It made it so much clear. 

I am guessing you are tipping me to read more about "Linearity of Expectation"?

Comment: Well...I'd always advocate that someone read more about linearity of expectation, but if all you care about is this particular question, there may be a way to unroll it so that you get a nice answer (or at least a higher-quality estimate of the answer). I personally hate this kind of question because I always get messed up in the algebra, so I'm not the one who should address that.

Comment: I can't ask for more. I liked your intuition more than the answer itself. I'll try to get around to finding a way to compute it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define
$$
X_i = \mathbb{1}\{i \text{ is picked}\}.
$$
Notice that its expected value is
$$
\mathbb{E} X_i = \mathbb{P}[i\ \text{is picked}]
= 1 - \mathbb{P}[i\ \text{not picked}]
= 1 - \Big(1 - \frac{1}{1000}\Big)^N.
$$
To be clear here, we choose to look at the complementary event of $\{i\ \text{is picked}\}$ because whenever $i$ is picked it can happen in a variety of ways, maybe it was picked once, maybe a lot of times. However, on the complementary event we just have to ask that $i$ was not picked in any of the $N$ attempts.

---

The random variable that counts how many different numbers were picked is simply
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i
$$
and its expected value is
$$
\mathbb{E} \Big[ \sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i \Big]
= 1000 \cdot \Big[1 - \Big(1 - \frac{1}{1000}\Big)^N\Big].
$$
Just to emphasize some important aspects of the problem, notice that the $X_i$ are not independent, since knowing that $i$ was picked makes it less probable that the other numbers were also picked. However, here we are just using *linearity of expectation* to separate into individual $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ and then the fact that since we are choosing each number uniformly, the above expectation is equal for every value of $i$.

---

Finally, I checked the expected value for $N = 10, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5$, using [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B1000*%281+-+%28999%2F1000%29%5E%2810%5En%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+5%7D%5D+%2F%2FN). The corresponding values were respectively:

$$
9.95512, 95.2079, 632.305, 999.955, 1000
$$

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for filling in the actual computation here (and particularly for including the numerical results).

Comment: Daniel, you are the man.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

for given $N$ you would like to compute average number of distinct integers so:

$$\sum_{\sum x_i = N} (\sum_{j=1}^{1000}1_{x_j>0})\frac{N!}{x_{1}!x_{2}!...x_{1000}!}(\frac{1}{1000})^N$$

this is the formula in general I don't know if it can be simplified

Comment: Cool. So much to learn about.